# UIKeyboardDidShowNotification notification delivered twice

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

My view controller is subscribing to `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` in `viewWillAppear` and unsubscribing in `viewWillDisappear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardShown)
           name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
         object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardShown
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard shown");
}
```

I'm also setting:

```
self.collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

It makes the keyboard disappear as I start dragging the main collecting view.

The problem is that `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is delivered *twice*. Once when I focus the text field, as expected, and once as I start dragging the scroll view, when the keyboard actually *disappears*.

Is this a bug or a feature, or something I'm doing wrong? What are my alternatives for listening to actual "keyboard shown/hidden" without extra spurious events?

Comment: What is the use of UIKeyboardDidShowNotification here? I mean if you want to perform any action when your keyboard appear or disappear then I think textfield delegate methods will also work for you.

Comment: @TechNet-Weblineindia I need it to make a `UITextField` *inside* the accessory active (similar to messages app). I have a fake `UITextField` that actually triggers the initial one, and after the keyboard is shown, text field inside accessory becomes the first responder.

Comment: Ok. I am not sure whether this will work or not for you based on your requirement but may be you can try to add Keyboard Hide notification as well. So when UIKeyboardDidShowNotification will call, unsubscribe it. And again subscribe it when Keyboard hide notification call.

Comment: If you breakpoint viewWillAppear does it hit more than once?